# unable to connect to sparklyr from RStudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I am trying to connect to spark from RStudio. Currently we are using Cloudera Hadoop distribution where the Spark (2.2) is running. I tested everything from edge node, I was able to create Spark context and execute my queries as well. Everything works fine till yesterday from RStudio, suddenly we have issues from RStudio.

```
library(dplyr)    
library(sparklyr)   
config <- spark_config()    
config$spark.driver.memory <- "8G"    
config$spark.executor.memory <- "8G"    
config$spark.executor.executor <- "2"    
config$spark.executor.cores <- "4"    
config$spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max <- "2000m"    
config$spark.driver.maxResultSize <- "4G"    
config$spark.akka.frameSize <- "768"    
sc <- spark_connect(master="yarn-client",     
version="2.2.0",    
 config=config,     
spark_home = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2')
```

```
Error in force(code) : 
  Failed while connecting to sparklyr to port (8880) for sessionid (14727): Sparklyr gateway did not respond while retrieving ports information after 60 seconds
    Path: /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.2.0.cloudera1-1.cdh5.12.0.p0.142354/lib/spark2/bin/spark-submit
    Parameters: --class, sparklyr.Shell, '/usr/lib64/R/library/sparklyr/java/sparklyr-2.2-2.11.jar', 8880, 14727
    Log: /tmp/RtmpoNJQEH/file151b437c0313b_spark.log


---- Output Log ----
18/11/12 13:54:50 INFO sparklyr: Session (14727) is starting under 127.0.0.1 port 8880
18/11/12 13:54:50 INFO sparklyr: Session (14727) found port 8880 is not available
18/11/12 13:54:50 INFO sparklyr: Backend (14727) found port 8884 is available
18/11/12 13:54:50 INFO sparklyr: Backend (14727) is registering session in gateway
18/11/12 13:54:50 INFO sparklyr: Backend (14727) is waiting for registration in gateway

---- Error Log ----
```

I verified the version for sparklyr as well, it was 0.9.2

Can some please let me know what could be the wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
library(httr)
library(sparklyr)
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2')
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/conf/yarn-conf/')
config <- list()
config=c(config,list("sparklyr.shell.deploy-mode"="client"))
httr::with_config(
  config = httr::authenticate(user=":", password="", type="gssnegotiate"),
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", version = "2.2.0", config = config))
sc
```

If you have SSL and Kerberos enabled, you may need to use this option

```
library(httr)
library(sparklyr)
set_config(config(cainfo = "/opt/cloudera/security/global_cacerts.pem"))
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2')
Sys.setenv(YARN_CONF_DIR = '/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/conf/yarn-conf/')
config <- list()
config=c(config,list("sparklyr.shell.keytab"="/PATH/PATH.keytab",
"sparklyr.shell.principal"="user@DOMAIN.COM",
"sparklyr.shell.deploy-mode"="client"
))
httr::with_config(
  config = httr::authenticate(user=":", password="", type="gssnegotiate"),
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", version = "2.2.0", config = config))
sc
```

Note: Replace cainfo with your Root CA path in pem format, Specify the user keytab in sparklyr.shell.keytab and Specify UPN(user principal name) in sparklyr.shell.principal